# In Firefox SPAN elements cannot be dynamically added to elements with -column-width values

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, multiple-columns

I noticed that Chrome handles pretty well cases where span elements are dynamically added to existing elements with the -column-width CSS property applied to it. However, Firefox does not. In this simple example bellow, we have a javascript function called addSpan() that creates a span element and attaches it to the div with id = "content". This DIV happens to have the -column-width property applied to it. If you run this code on Chrome, the addSpan() function correctly adds a new span element at the end of the content. On Firefox, it simply breaks the whole column layout.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Add a bunch of text inside of the content div to make sure you see at least 3 columns.

```
<style>

    #wrapper {
       width:200px;
       height:300px;
    }

    #content {
      height:300px;
      column-width: 200px;
      -moz-column-width: 200px;
      -webkit-column-width: 200px;
    }

</style>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
Bunch of text here.
</div>
</div>


<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="addSpan()">Click Me!</a>

<script>

function addSpan() {
    var sp = document.createElement("span");
    sp.innerHTML = "Something!";
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(sp);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. As I suspected, its a matter of forcing Firefox to redraw elements. The problem is fixed after adding the following line to the addSpan( ) function.

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
```

Comment: This solution BTW destroys any listeners attached to elements inside or on the DIV#content